# setting current slider value as variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a simple man. Thus, I have a simple question. 
I want to set the value of a variable which I named myFreq equal to  the current value from my slider. The myFreq value will be used in a function that plays a sin wave(timbre.js). I have the current value updating to a paragraph in the html, but I I don't understand how to set it as the value for the myFreq variable.

```
var myFreq;

$(function(){

var slider = $('#slider'),
    min = slider.attr('min'),
    max = slider.attr('max'),
    currentValue = $('#currentValue');
// Hiding the slider:
slider.hide();
$('#control').knobKnob({
    snap : 10,
    value: 500,
    turn : function(ratio){
        // Changing the value of the hidden slider
        slider.val(Math.round(ratio*(max-min) + min));
        // Updating the current value text
        currentValue.html(slider.val());
    }
}); 
});

function playT(){T("sin", {freq:myFreq}).play();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `#slider` is an HTML5 input with a type of "range", you could just have jQuery listen to its change event like so:

```
$('#slider').on('change', function(){
    myFreq = $(this).val();
});
```

That will update `myFreq` with the current slider value every time the slider's change event is fired.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, #slider is an HTML5 with type of "range." While I've got you, where would new code so I can test it out?

Comment: You could put this code anywhere inside the `$(function(){});`

Comment: var myFreq;
$(function(){

var slider = $('#slider'),
    min = slider.attr('min'),
    max = slider.attr('max'),
    currentValue = $('#currentValue');
// Hiding the slider:
slider.hide();
$('#control').knobKnob({
    snap : 10,
    value: 200,
    turn : function(ratio){
        // Changing the value of the hidden slider
        slider.val(Math.round(ratio*(max-min) + min));
        // Updating the current value text
        currentValue.html(slider.val());
    }
});

$('#slider').on('change', function(){
    myFreq = $(this).val();
});

});



T("sin", {freq:myFreq}).play();

Comment: I tried this along with various other configurements with no success. I removed the function that contains the "T" timbre object that plays the sin wave too so now it just reads, T("sin", {freq:myFreq}).play(); The code causes a sin wave to be played on pageload when the myFreq var is set to a number such as, var myFreq=300; at the declaration outside the $(function(){}); but not inside it.

Comment: I've been working on this for a while and I've only found one example which used:`Sin.prototype.set = function(freq) {
    this.container.find('input').val(freq);
    return this.load();
  };` where 'Sin' is a function containing the code to play sin wave, as well, as bind and load.